# Why are set operations always showed with a Venn Diagram where both A and B are intersecting?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification, proof-writing

So there is this question involving the pictorial representations of set *operations* (i.e. $A - B$).

In each Venn Diagram, the *A* and *B* circles (sets) are always shown overlapping. For example, $A - B$:

[[image: <span class=]$A - B$">](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uszAG.png)

What if the circles $A$ and $B$ were separate? How would defining the set operation be showed? Thanks.

Comment: If the circles do not overlap, then this depicts the sets being disjoint, i.e. $A\cap B=\emptyset.$ The overlap represents the intersection: the elements that are in both sets. Beyond that, I'm not sure I understand your question.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen Hi, okay so if the sets are disjoint, why isn't that the case when describing i.e. $A - B$. Why is it that they are always joint when showing the different set operations?

Comment: They are shading the region that represents the set. The red region is $A-B$ (if $A$ is the right circle and $B$ is the left circle). If the circles didn't overlap, all of $A$ would be red. This means that if $A\cap B=\emptyset,$ then $A-B = A.$

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen Okay, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Venn diagrams, the circles are shown to intersect each other to provide for all possible scenarios. Now dots (representing elements) that lie in both circles in such diagrams represent elements that belong to both sets, and if these two sets are disjoint (have no elements in common), that just means that there are really no dots lying in both circles. If the circles were drawn as non-intersecting, there would be no way to represent elements that belong to both sets.

Comment: Okay, this makes senses, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you are using $A-B$ to denote $A\setminus B$, and that the right-hand circle is $A$, while the other is $B$. If the circles were not overlapping, then $A\cap B=\emptyset$. In that case:$$A-B=A\setminus B=A$$

Comment: Okay, this is good additional information to the question. Thanks.